# How can i use same component multiple time in different files with different CSS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

I have created a separate file where I have data that will repeat multiple times and export that file

```
export default const Truck = [
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Door pick-up and delivery",
},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Heavy weight shipments",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Same day delivery in city limits",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Bullet Service",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Cheque collection and return service",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "E-commerce solution",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "API Integration",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Real Time tracking on website",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Delivery next day to all the Emirates in UAE",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "Personalized service by qualified personnel",

},
{
    icon: <i className="fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal"></i>,
    text: "All packages scanned thru Handheld Scanners by trained staff’s, enabling online track & trace",

}
```

]

Then I have created separate components where I am getting all the  data by applying map function

```
import Truck from "./CssforUlList"
import "./new.scss"
import React from 'react'
export const UlServicesItems = (theme) => {

return (


    < div >
        {
            Truck.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index} >
                        <span >{item.icon}</span>
                        <span >{item.text}</span>
                    </li>

                )
            })
        }
    </div >
)
```

and finally, I am importing the map function component in the main file

```
import { UlServicesItems } from './UlServicesItems/UlServicesItems';
  <UlServicesItems />
```

Now the problem is how can I apply a separate CSS class to component

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having your icon component defined in the Truck array can we just have the Truck array to return

```
{
    className: "fa fa-truck fa-flip-horizontal",
    text: "Personalized service by qualified personnel",

},
```

Now you can add the icon component inside your return as

```
Truck.map(({className, text}, index) => {
                return (
                    <li key={index} >
                        <span><i className={className} /></span>
                        <span>{item.text}</span>
                    </li>

                )
            })
```

Comment: i have to run same compontnt multiple time with different css

Comment: No issue on icon